# Using Expect to configue Cisco banners

Tags: expect, cisco

I'm using expect scripts to reconfigure a bunch of Cisco routers. Mostly, its working well, I have a file of addresses that is read by a script, which passes the addresses, one at a time to another script that logs on, goes into enable mode, then pulls a series of router configuration commands from a test file, which it issues to the router.

That worked well until I tried to script the logon banner. In this process, you issue the router a command line with a delimiter character, then follow that with whatever you want to have as a banner, formatted as you want to see it, then finish the banner off with a second delimiter character.

That gives a problem: when you move from one line to the next (with C/R) when building the banner, each new line starts with just a blank line (unlike a successful command, which will open a new line with #). That means that expect has no trigger to let it know to place the next line of banner, so it hangs.

I've tried things with embedded "\n" and "0x0a" to no avail.

has anyone any suggestions? has anyone succeeded in doing this before?

Comment: Try `\r\n` instead of `\n`. Or `\r` itself can be sufficent.

Comment: OK, I fixed it. Expect is waiting for the # prompt before it provides the next line. If you end each line of the banner with a #, it works, even though the C/R and # are round the wrong way. It may not be the most tidy programming but it works

Answer (score 0):

OK, I fixed it. Expect is waiting for the # prompt before it provides the next line. If you end each line of the banner with a #, it works, even though the C/R and # are round the wrong way. It may not be the most tidy programming but it works